# Scipy: Sum over sparse matrix: "ValueError: could not convert integer scalar"

Tags: scipy, integer, sparse-matrix, scalar, valueerror

For certain inputs, I get an "ValueError: could not convert integer scalar", in the following code:

```
a, b = np.array(l), np.array( [i for i in xrange(M.shape[1]) if not i in set(l)] );
c    = np.ravel( M[np.ix_(a,b)].sum(0) );
```

where `M` is a sparse matrix, `l` is a list of length 10766 and `M.shape==(249109,249109)`.

I am guessing that the problem occurs in `.sum(0)` as this returns a dense matrix, but `len(a_)` and `M.shape[1]` are nowhere near `2**31`.

Could there be any other explanation?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 314, in __getitem__
num_samples, row.ravel(), col.ravel(), val)
ValueError: could not convert integer scalar
```

Comment: 1. Shouldn't `b` be defined on the columns of `M` (i.e. `M.shape[1]`)?
2. I don't think the call to ravel is necessary since the sum should return a 1-D array assuming M is 2-D.
However, these do not explain the value error. What are the dtypes of `a_, b_, M`?

Comment: Yes `M` is quadratic, so this is  why I had no bug, but it should be `shape[1]`, the ravel is not necessary in this line but in the next line I have a column vector and do the same, so I just want a flat array with the sums...

Comment: `M` is a sparse scipy bool matrix in csr format, `a_` is a list and `b_` is a set. I know now that the problem occurs when N.shape[1] is somewhere around 300k, while 150k works at least in some cases. So nowhere near the `2**31`.

Comment: Details that you put in the comments should be in the body of question.  The question should also have a [MCVE] that we can copy and test (or at least run in our heads).

Comment: I'll try to find an input example though I am not sure how to publish a very large dense matrix here...